# stereotype user model implementation in Apache Mahout

Tags: recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender

I working on implementation of both individual and stereotype user model in recommendation system. I came across with Apache Mahout but it seems that it only works with individual user model.
**My question is how can i work with stereo type user model in Apache Mahout Taste?**

My understanding for the recommendation engine is 
that you have these core parameters

- Method of information acquisition (Implicit or explicit)
- User model (Individual or stereotype)
- Recommendation techniques (Collaborative or content base)

Answer (score 0):

Taste is being deprecated. Mahout has undergone a major reboot and no longer accepts Hadoop MapReduce code. Many of the Hadoop MapReduce algorithms have been rewritten on the Mahout Samsara codebase that virtualizes a great deal of linear algebra type operations to run on multiple compute engines. The most complete is Spark, which runs something like 10x faster than Hadoop MapReduce.

That as a preamble the new "recommender" implementations, although they include ALS, also have code for item and row similarity, which in recommender data means item and user similarity.

See the description of "spark-rowsimilarity" here: http://mahout.apache.org/users/algorithms/intro-cooccurrence-spark.html#2-spark-rowsimilarity

The example is wrong for your case but works just as well to compute user similarities by inputting user interaction vectors.

Another way to do this is put user interaction vectors into a similarity engine that uses Lucene like Solr or Elasticsearch. Then query with a specific user's data and you will get back similar users.